# Searching for a date in a dataframe and calculate in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
   survey_date point_id
1      29/05/18 38023064
2      28/05/18 38003068
3      10/07/18 40903100
4      22/09/18 39522778
5      20/06/18 45003106
6      19/06/18 37142694
7      16/07/18 37983124
8      19/06/18 37763062
```

and the second one:

```
point_id temp_2018.01.01 temp_2018.01.02 temp_2018.01.03 temp_2018.01.04 temp_2018.01.05
1 31101626           12.97           11.47           13.74           13.73           12.79
2 26841812           11.65           11.32           14.53           13.97           13.15

.... for all the year 2018 (so 366 columns)
```

what I want to do is to take each survey date of the first dataframe, search for it in the second dataframe's columns in order to extract the sum of the values in the entire month BEFORE the survey date, related to the same point.

I couldn't come up with a solution so far. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but try it out!

```
dates1 <- df$survey_date # extract dates
dates1 <- as.Date(dates1,format = "%d/%m/%y") # change format
dates_col <- gsub(x = dates1,pattern = "-",replacement = ".") # replace "-" by dot

namecol <- paste("temp_",dates_col,sep="") # recreate colnames

place <- which(colnames(df2)==namecol) # in which place is the column?
```

Since you have 365 columns + first column, the sum should start at col 2:

```
value <- sum(df2[ ,2:(place-1)]) # sum that values from column 2 to the day minus one, since you don't want the value of that day
```

**EDIT:**

So in a loop:

```
value <- c(); p <- 1; # After edit
for (i in df$survey_date){
dates1 <- as.Date(i,format = "%d/%m/%y")
dates_col <- gsub(x = dates1,pattern = "-",replacement = ".")
    
namecol <- paste("temp_",dates_col,sep="")
    
#place <- which(colnames(df2)==namecol) # Before edit
place <- which(colnames(df2[ ,2:ncol(df2)])==namecol) #After edit
#value[i] <- sum(df2[ ,2:(place-1)]) # Before edit
value[p] <- sum(df2[ ,2:(place)]) # After edit
p <- p+1 # After edit
}
```

Finally, use `mutate()` or `cbind()`

```
df <- cbind(df, value)
```

Comment: I think this could be the right way to do it, but when I run the following line:
```
place <- which(colnames(df2)==namecol)
```
it gives me this message:
```
Warning in colnames(lucas_meteo_rain) == namecol :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```
and the output is an integer vector of 9 elements (I guess with the found position of some date (i'm not sure which one))

Comment: @dasatell3 seems that "point_id" is the only column with different name than "namecol". So you have "n" days and your df2 is "n+1" columns. I think this is the problem, so try:  ``place <- which(colnames(df2[ ,2:ncol(df2)])==namecol)``. By this way you're selecting the columns whose name corresponds to the same values of the vector "namecol". Be aware that this now takes ``place<-place+1`` since you have moved one column to the right. Be aware too of the next error, that is: ``value[i] <- sum(df2[ ,2:(place-1)])``. Error 1: "i" is not an index, but a date. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: ok, I see what you did, not selecting the column id_point which I don't need to search for...but it stil gives me the same error after running `place <- which(colnames(df2[ ,2:ncol(df2)])==namecol)`:
`Warning in colnames(df2[, 2:ncol(df2)]) == namecol :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

I guess it's trying to compare two vector with the same length, which is not the case. So maybe the function "which" is not the right one for the case?